# Regular upgrade gives unmet dependency error

Tags: upgrade, dependencies

Was doing regular update via Ubuntu software got unmet dependency error for Python 3.5.

Tried `apt-get upgrade` got the error below.

What next?

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package python3.5 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

$ apt-cache policy python 3 python 3.5
python:
  Installed: 2.7.11-1
  Candidate: 2.7.11-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.11-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
python:
  Installed: 2.7.11-1
  Candidate: 2.7.11-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.11-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
python3.5-cups:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
python3.5-reportlab-accel:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
python3.5-venv:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libpython3.5:
  Installed: 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.3
  Candidate: 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.3
  Version table:
 *** 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.3 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
python3.5:
  Installed: 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1
  Candidate: 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
python3.5-minimal:
  Installed: 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1
  Candidate: 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
python3.5-apt:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
python3.5-renderpm:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
python3.5-doc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
python3.5-dbus:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
python3.5-lxml:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
python3.5-gdbm:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libpython3.5-stdlib:
  Installed: 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1
  Candidate: 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libreoffice-l10n-3.5:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libpython3.5-minimal:
  Installed: 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1
  Candidate: 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libmwaw-0.3-3v5:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
povray-3.5:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
N: Unable to locate package 3
```

Comment: What Ubuntu version is it? please [edit] your question to include the output of command `apt-cache policy python3 python3.5`

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score -1):

Run

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all python3
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3
```

Comment: I get the following error -The package python3.5 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Comment: I've edit the answer, could you try it now?

Comment: Your suggestion worked, I then had to install Python 3.5, but all seems good now. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome. Can  you vote the answer up please.

Comment: I'd like to but I'm too new! Thanks again.